# Corrupted WinXP Partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

I corrupted my default partition, after I had made a 2nd partition while trying to do a dual-boot. I then installed WinXP on the 2nd empty partition and now I'm able to view all my files except those which are locked by my user. I need to fix my AUTOEXEC file so I can boot into it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows XP, you can try to restart your computer with DOS prompt and use the fdisk /mbr command:

```
fdisk /mbr
```

You can use that to rewrite the master boot record and change which partitions you can boot into without writing over the data on your partitions.

Comment: @Mat  I'm sorry I thought that it was a programming issue and that I could get assistance with my problem. Thank you fuzzyanalysis, I will try that.

Comment: @fuzzyanaliysis How would I restart into the DOS prompt? I thought that was only in Win98. My email is: **etaripnoit@gmail.com** so I don't get in more trouble for posting this question on the wrong site.

Comment: You can try and insert the Win98 CD into the PC and choose to boot it with DOS prompt.  Then do the fdisk /mbr.

Comment: But I have WinXP on the partition, does that matter?

Comment: fdisk /mbr won't erase your partition, it will help configure it.

Comment: How do I use the disc? I put it in and then what? step by step?

Comment: You have to change your BIOS to boot from CDROM as your first device.  Have you ever changed your BIOS before?  You should read up on how to do that.  Once you boot from CDROM you should be able to read the prompts and boot to DOS to type in FDISK /mbr.

Comment: I'm just going to make a video of my problem because nobody can seem to get it. I'll comment again with a link to the video. Maybe in a week, sorry I'm busy.